# Hbase: Getting One row key from each and every region

Tags: hbase

Is there a way to get one row key from each and every region? The way I have been doing it right now is sequentially scanning each and every region for first rowkey but that is super slow. Was wondering if there is any other better way.

PS: Please don't ask why I need one random row key from each region :)

Answer (score 0):

Try **public byte[] getStartKey()** provided by [class HRegion](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/HRegion.html) if you wish to get the starting row key of a particular region.

Alternatively you can use **public byte[][] getStartKeys()** available in [class HTable](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html) if you want to get the starting row key for **every region** in the currently open table.

**EDIT :**

Try [public byte[] getStartKey()](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HRegionInfo.html#getStartKey%28%29) provided by HRegionInfo(tested personally).

I have a table called TestTable with 4 regions and the start key of the of the second region is 0001617355. See the picture below :

[image]

And if I do :

> System.out.println("Key as String : " +
>   Bytes.toString(HRegionInfo.getStartKey(Bytes.toBytes("TestTable,0001617355,1375740446704.68797fdaa6410c7f21d09444d649758c."))));

on this region it gives me :

Key as String : **0001617355**

Is this what you need?

(I think there should be some way to achieve it through HTable and HRegion as well. Will try that out and let you know).

HTH

Comment: getStartKeys() in HTable or getStartKey() in HRegion returns region start boundary i.e. it uses metadata of the table to return start row. It doesn't return actual row present in the table.
e.g: If a table has 2 regions with boundary [000-001] and [001-002] and the first rowKey in first region is 00012345, HTable. getStartKeys() is going to return 000 for first region while what I am interested in is getting 00012345 for first region.

Comment: Since I haven't tested them personally, I can't comment anything right now. But I have used getStartKey available in HRegionInfo and it works(I don't know how did I miss that in the answer. updating it right now).